# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list with two items. The second item's ID is generated by `getTime()` and concatenated with `new$`, forming a random ID as shown in the image below.

[image]

I need to target that element to perform some functions, but when I try to do that using `querySelector`, it produces an error saying that it is not a valid selector, even when I use `String()` to covert the generated random number to a string.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Post your code as text, not images.

Comment: Does `document.getElementById(elements[1].id)` work for you?  If so, I would hazard a guess that it is erroring on the `$`

Comment: Your target ID and actual ID differ, and appear to be randomly-generated. You'll need a different selector, such as the first child of `#itemList`.

Comment: @Taplar yes it works.

Comment: `$` has special meaning in selectors. Use a different character or escape it with backslashes.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#' + elements[1].id.replace('$', '\\$') + ' .item')`

Comment: @Barmar removing `$` solved the problem. thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selecting elements with a particular ID using the `#` syntax doesn't allow for  an unescaped `$`s inside the ID. You could bypass this by selecting the parent element via `[id="<some id>"]` instead:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('[id="foo$bar"] .item')
);
```

```html
<div id="foo$bar">
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
</div>
```

Or escape the `$` with a backslash first:

```js
const idSelector = 'foo$bar'.replace(/\$/g, '\\$');
console.log(
  document.querySelector('#' + idSelector + ' .item')
);
```

```html
<div id="foo$bar">
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```js
document.querySelector("[id='your-id-here-with-special-char']")
```

should work. let me know

Answer (score 1):

Also try this:

```
document.getElementById(id)
```

I've tested on a maximum of 10 randomly generated integers, and NPM **uuid** (which is like 32 bits of numbers idk it's a lot).